# How to multiply (2) cols from (2) different tables and input the results in a new col created in (1) of the tables

Tags: php, mysql

1. I have (2) tables within a database: Products, ProductSold

**Prodcuts**

```
--------------------    
| id | name | cost |    
--------------------    
101  | Jeans|  32       
102  | shoes|  53
```

**ProductSold**

```
----------------------------
| strNum | amtSold | sales |
----------------------------
 100    |   83    |  NULL
 100    |  105    |  NULL
```

2. I need to multiply the (amountSold * cost) columns.
3. I need to input the results in the column “sales” which is located in the   ProductSold table.

*Note: I have a php script that connects to my db, fetches the data within, and displays it in a html table.

---

### |Product Number | Product Description | Store | QTR | Amount Sold | Cost | Sales |

```
  101                Jeans           100    1          83        32
  102                Shoes           100    1         105        53
```

Comment: How do you know that the amount sold is 83 for jeans?

Comment: It is given. The only data not given is the sales column.

Comment: What I mean is, there's no column connecting  the products and product sales table so how can you get that information?

Comment: Actually there is --->             $sql = "select p.productId, 
         p.name, 
         ps.storeNumber, 
         ps.qtr, 
         ps.amountSold, 
         p.cost,
         ps.sales
         FROM Products p 
         inner join ProductSold ps
         on ps.productId = p.productId 
         where storeNumber = 100";

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This isn't that hard assuming your database is set up correctly, which in this case it is not. Right now, you don't have a `productId` column in your `ProductSold` table, meaning `amtSold` means nothing, as we don't know WHAT was sold. So, your table should look like this:

```
id | strNum | prodId | amtSold
1  | 100    | 101    | 83
2  | 100    | 102    | 105
```

So that the calculations can be done here. For your select statement, it would be something like:

```
SELECT p.prodId, p.name, ps.strNum, p.cost, ps.amtSold FROM ProductSold ps, (p.cost * ps.amtSold) AS profit 
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.id = ps.id;
```

To get the basic info. This would return:

```
prodId | name  | strNum | cost | amtSold | profit
=================================================
101    | Jeans | 100    | 32   | 83      | 2656
102    | Shoes | 100    | 53   | 105     | 5565
```

Now, you don't need to store profit directly in the database as long as your query has that calculation on it. Hope this helped!